# Excel load csv file without removing leading zeros

Tags: excel

I want to implement "Download to device" functionality, which calls and API request which generates a CSV file.
Everything works as it should, except if I open file in Excel and the column has leading zeros (0001), it removes them (1). I would like to view them properly in excel as well (if I open csv in notepad, leading zeros are still there)

API request:

```
var resp = await Client.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUrl));
if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using (var stream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();                       
        }
    }
    return DownloadReportResponse.Success(result);
}
```

Call method on .Droid project:
await App.Helper.FileHelpter.SaveTextToFile(fileName, reportRes.FileContent, true, false);

SaveTextToFile method:

```
public async Task SaveTextToFile(string filename, string text, bool external, bool append)
{
    var path = CreatePathToFile(filename, external);
    using (StreamWriter sw = (append) ? File.AppendText(path) : File.CreateText(path))
    {
        await sw.WriteAsync(text);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Thats kinda it. Everything works as it should, except those leading zeros...
If you have any other way to save files, you can recommend it and I will try if it will work. Thanks!

Comment: this is how Excel works.  If it thinks a column is numeric it will strip leading 0s.  You can try enclosing the value in `"` or prepending a `'` to force Excel to treat it as text instead of numeric.

Comment: Yeah but its weird, if I call this request from the browser and download excel, it doesnt remove leading zeros. If I download it from mobile  app (GET request ->reading stream -> saving to device, it removes zeros... And there arent any additional " or '.

Comment: Have you actually examined the raw text file from the two different methods?  They should be identical.

Comment: sometimes it works, sometimes not... if you want excel to automatically separate by comma  you can add sep=, to csv. Is there anything like that to force excel to think tha columns are texts and not numbers?

Comment: Google `excel load csv keep leading zeroes`. Its a common excel question. With a well-documented answer. Has nothing to do with xamarin, downloading, your app, file saving, or anything else mentioned in question. Its just excel. I’ve edited title and tags correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to view them properly in excel as well (if I open csv in
> notepad, leading zeros are still there

If the zeros are there in notepad then everything works as it should regarding your code.

Your column is interpreted as numerical column in Excel so it is imported like that. You can either add some data so that Excel doesn't get confused (some non-numerical character in the column), or possibly use some other tool like LibreOffice Calc and see if it treats the values differently. You can also submit feedback to Microsoft so that this gets fixed in Excel if you consider it as a bug.